# Activeadmin custom filter label is not registering I18n locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, internationalization, activeadmin

I have a few custom filters in my activeadmin dashboard tabs, and I have set the filter label to read its corresponding translation from 3 different translation files. This is the only translation in my app that isn't working/changing when the user toggles to a different language. When I remove the translation altogether and reload the page, the error tells me that activeadmin is indeed looking to the wrong translation file in its "translation missing" error. Does activeadmin do some sort of caching of custom filter labels? Is there a way to force lookup of locale for these labels?

I've confirmed that my `set_locale` is working consistently in `application_controller`. I've tried re-checking/force checking locale redundantly from the activadmin ruby file, but I have not done this successfully. I've tried reading the translation with varying methods from the rails docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations
I also printed out `I18n.locale` at the top of the active admin file for the resource, and it prints out the previous language code (before the user toggle). I tried forcing the locale by passing it as the 2nd arg to the label translation as well.

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
```

```
filter :space,
         label: I18n.t('.activeadmin.labels.space_names'),
         collection: proc { Space.order(:name) }
```

When the url includes `es` and all other translations are rendering in Spanish, the custom filter language is still English. When I remove the translation, the error is: `TRANSLATION MISSING: EN.ACTIVEADMIN.LABELS.SPACE_NAMES`
Why are these the only translations looking to the `EN` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, the custom label has to be passed as a proc:

`label: proc{I18n.t('.activeadmin.labels.space_names')}`